# Folder is emptied after installation of an RPM package

Tags: redhat, rpm, yum, rhel8, dnf

I am reading RPM packages from a CSV file and want to install them one after the other. If there is a "yes" or "ja" at the end of the line, the package is to be installed. Otherwise it should be skipped. The packages have already been downloaded and saved in the folder `/var/tmp/updcache`.

On RHEL 7, this works wonderfully.
On RHEL 8, after installing the first package, the entire `/var/tmp/updcache` folder is emptied. So the installation attempt of the second package in the CSV file fails because it is no longer there. Likewise all other packages in the CSV.

What is the best way to prevent this? Is there an option for `dnf` that prevents the deletion?

Here is the script ...

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    linecount=$(( $linecount+1 )) 
        if [[ "$line" == *yes ]] || [[ "$line" == *ja ]]; then
            package="$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[;].*$//')" 
            echo $package >> ./InstallationLog_$curdate.log
            dnf install -y -q /var/tmp/updcache/$package &>> ./InstallationLog_$curdate.log
            log="$(rpm -qa | grep -c $packageStat)"
        elif [[ "$line" == *no ]] || [[ "$line" == *nein ]]; then
            package="$(echo "$line" | sed 's/[;].*$//')"
            echo "Installation of $package was skipped!"
        fi
done <$install_list
```

Comment: Please take note that your question is only about using system tools, administration and configuration and therefore suited better on other sites like serverfault.com, superuser.com, unix.stackexchange.com, etc. Here it seems to be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> *What is the best way to prevent this? Is there an option for `dnf` that prevents the deletion?*

In order to prevent `dnf` from auto cleaning the cache after or before package installation you may need to set according `man dnf.conf` in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf` under section

```ini
[main]
...
keepcache=True
...
```

> *Keeps downloaded packages in the cache when set to `True`. Even if it is set to `False` and packages have not been installed they will still persist until next successful transaction. The default is `False`.*

You may also have a look into `dnf --help`.

> *`-C`, `--cacheonly`       run entirely from system cache, don't update cache*

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to enable package caching in `dnf`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225972/)